# Pass multiple R objects (integers, strings, etc) to SQL query within R

Tags: sql, r

I would like to execute a query that relies on multiple R vectors to more efficiently gather data and decrease post-processing. I have been trying in R but also RMD as it has built in SQL chunks. Solutions for R and/or R studio would be welcomed.

The vectors would be something similar to:

```
con <- dbConnect(odbc(), "dbname")

FY1 <- c(2010, 2011, 2012)
FY2 <- c(2015, 2016)
FY3 <- c(2019, 2020)

YEAR_VECTOR <- c(FY1, FY2, FY3)
COLOR_VECTOR <- c("BLUE", "RED", "GREEN")
```

And they would be passed into the following:

```
{sql, connection = con, output.var = "data"}
SELECT
  MONTH,
  YEAR, 
  COLOR
FROM database
WHERE YEAR IN ?YEAR_VECTOR
AND COLOR IN ?COLOR_VECTOR
```

Comment: If you use `dbplyr` you can actually use `dplyr` syntax and it will write SQL statements for you to execute. It can be built in steps and won't execute on the server until you trigger it at the end with `collect()`. Perhaps that is an option as well. Check the [vignette](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/dbplyr/vignettes/dbplyr.html).

Answer (score 0):

I've never used SQL chunks in RMarkdown before, but you could use `DBI::sqlInterpolate` to create a query you can then execute using `dbGetQuery` or something similar:

```
library(DBI)

# con <- dbConnect(odbc(), "dbname")
con <- dbConnect(RSQLite::SQLite(), ":memory:")

FY1 <- c(2010, 2011, 2012)
FY2 <- c(2015, 2016)
FY3 <- c(2019, 2020)

YEAR_VECTOR <- c(FY1, FY2, FY3)
COLOR_VECTOR <- c("BLUE", "RED", "GREEN")

make_sql_condition <- function(MY_VEC, string = TRUE) {
  SQL(
    paste(
      paste0(
        if(string) "'" else NULL, 
        MY_VEC, 
        if(string) "'" else NULL
        ),
      collapse = ", "
    )
  )
} 


query <- DBI::sqlInterpolate(con, 
                    "SELECT MONTH, YEAR, COLOR FROM database WHERE YEAR IN (?) AND COLOR IN (?)",
                    make_sql_condition(YEAR_VECTOR, string = FALSE),
                    make_sql_condition(COLOR_VECTOR))
```

This outputs a query you can then execute with `dbGetQuery(query)`:

```
SELECT MONTH, YEAR, COLOR FROM database WHERE YEAR IN (2010, 2011, 2012, 2015, 2016, 2019, 2020) AND COLOR IN ('BLUE', 'RED', 'GREEN')
```